# method readInt() is undefined for the type Scanner

Tags: java

I changed readInt to next int and it messed up the entire thing
the error eclipse is giving me is method readInt() is undefined for the type scanner. I'm fairly new to Java and have to create this Nim program for class. What am I missing here?

```
         System.out.print("Enter number of starting stones:");
         stones= Input.readInt();
         if (stones<= 0)
         {
```

Comment: Use `nextInt` and consult the javadocs

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is `nextInt()`:

```
stones= Input.nextInt();
```

Read [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextint.htm). Also, when you get an error that says the method is undefined, that means there is no method with that name. Make sure you spell the method name correct or referring to the correct method ([check out the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)).

Answer (score 0):

It is because the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class doesn't have a readInt method. It has [nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) that accepts no arguments and [nextInt(int radix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt(int)) that accepts an integer as a radix